# Call Mediator with Script Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I'm looking for an API with Call Mediator. Then I want to process the data coming with Script Mediaor and generate output with Respond. If I don't use Script Mediator, my stream will work. But when I want to use Script Mediaor I get the following error.

Unexpected character in preface '{' (code 123); expected '<'
in [row,col {unknown source}]: [1,1]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/x" name="x" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <script language="js"><![CDATA[var x = mc.getPayloadJSON();

if  (x.id == "1")
mc.setPayloadJSON('{"s":"success"}');
else 
mc.setPayloadJSON('{"s":"error"}');]]></script>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sending correct Content-Type with the message? If possible, please paste the entire API source xml.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. yes i am sending the content-type. I am sending the xml part in three parts. 

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/x" name="x" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>`

Comment: `<progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>`

Comment: `<script language="js"><![CDATA[var x = mc.getPayloadJSON();

if (x.id == "1")
mc.setPayloadJSON('{"s":"success"}');
else 
mc.setPayloadJSON('{"s":"error"}');]]></script>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>`

Comment: Please correctly format the source and add it to the question. You can edit the question and add it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Script Mediator` is a [content-aware](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/about-mediators/#classification-of-mediators) mediator and when you add a content-aware mediator to the mediation flow the message will be built(Binary message converted into a readable format) and brought into the mediation flow. This happens through [message builders](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/overview/key-concepts/#message-builders-and-formatters). From the error snippet you shared, it seems you are receiving a JSON message as a response. So there can be two reasons for this error.

1. As Arunan mentioned, your backend may not be sending the correct Content-Type as a header with the response.
2. The correct message builders are not set in the transport configurations to match the Content-Type header the backend is transmitting.

If you take the second case, first make sure a message builder is set for the default JSON content-type `application/json` in the `<SERVER_HOME>/conf/axis2/axis2.xml`. If it's there check if your backend is sending a JSON variation of a default content-type. For example "application/ld+json" etc. If that's the case you need to add a new message builder for this content type. You can refer to [this](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/setup/message_builders_formatters/message-builders-and-formatters/#configuring-message-buildersformatters) document if you are on MI. If you are on EI refer to [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Working+with+Message+Builders+and+Formatters#WorkingwithMessageBuildersandFormatters-Configuringmessagebuildersandformatters).

**Update**
After checking your comments, it looks like a straightforward integration. Other than the above two reasons this can be the backend altogether sending a wrong response. Are you using the browser to test this API? If so you may be getting a different response due to additional headers added by the browser. Hence please try removing all the transport headers before the call mediator. Refer to the below. Note the `<property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>`

```xml
<property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
<call>
    <endpoint>
        <http method="get" uri-template="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users">
            <suspendOnFailure>
                <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
            </suspendOnFailure>
            <markForSuspension>
                <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            </markForSuspension>
        </http>
    </endpoint>
</call>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @ycr . I tested it and it works.

Comment: Hello again,

It worked when I tested it via the link I gave yesterday. But it doesn't work when I want to send headers. Because Property Tool also deletes header. As you mentioned, I added the following builders to the axis2 (IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\conf\axis2) file. But when I run the application, it reconfigures the axis2 file and deletes the builders I added.

`<messageBuilder contentType="application/json" class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>  
<messageBuilder contentType="text/javascript" class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>`

Comment: @YusufUZUN before adding the builder did you check whether it's already there?  When adding this to Micro Integrator you have to add them into `deployment.toml` I have added the link to the document in my answer. If you are setting additional headers before the call mediator. Add the `<property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>` before setting the headers. Or you can set this as the first mediator in your API. Feel free to create a new question if you come across something new.

Comment: Perfect! Transport headers are a big problem.

```<property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>``` is the solution